# What is the difference between Schedule and Arrange?

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between "Arrange" and "Schedule"? How can I use these words in writing sentences and speaking? What are some examples of use?

Comment: To schedule is specifically time/diary related, but to arrange is not always. You can arrange a meeting in principle without there being a specific schedule.

Comment: You can also arrange the flowers on the table, the guest seating and books on the shelf.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of "Schedule" and"arrange" (as verbs) overlap, but are not identical. In some contexts they can be used interchangeably.

For example:

> - (1)  I scheduled a meeting for 3:00 pm tomorrow.
> - (2)  I arranged a meeting for 3:00 pm tomorrow.

Sentences (1) and (2) have very similar, possibly identical, meanings. However (1) **could** mean that the speaker has placed it on his or her **own** schedule, or on some official schedule, but has not yet secured agreement from other participants. Sentence (2) pretty clearly implies that agreement has been obtained, and (1) could  mean the same thing.

But "arrange" can cover making physical arrangements. In general "schedule" refers to setting a specific timer, while "arrange" may not. "arrange"  has a broader range of meaning.